# python pangram skipping over second letter

Tags: python, string, python-2.7

This is a function for a pangram that I wrote.
the `alpha[num]` for some reason takes `a,c,e,g` etc instead of taking `a,b,c,d,e` etc.

```
def ispangram(str1,alphabet=string.ascii_lowercase):

    alpha = []
    alpha += alphabet
    str1 = list(str1)
    for num in range(0,25):
        print num
        print alpha[num]
        for equal in str1:
            print equal
            if alpha[num] == equal:
                alpha.pop(num)
                print alpha
                break
            else:
                continue

    if alpha == none:
        print 'true'
    else:
        print 'false'
```

Answer (score 2):

You are modifying `alphabet` while iterating over it, which is causing your misses.

This code could be simplified considerably, though, improving the performance while you're at it. Instead of the double iteration, save your alphabet to a `set`, and iterate over the string, removing each character you encounter (O(1) operation in a `set`). When you're done iterating, if the `set` is empty, it means you've encountered every letter in your alphabet, making this string a pangram:

```
def ispangram(str1, alphabet = string.ascii_lowercase):

    alpha = set(alphabet)
    for ch in str1:
        if ch in alpha:
            alpha.remove(ch)

    return len(alpha) == 0
```

**EDIT:**
Actually, even more elegantly, you could convert both strings to `set`s and subtract them:

```
def ispangram(str1, alphabet = string.ascii_lowercase):

    alpha = set(alphabet)
    alpha -= set(str1)

    return len(alpha) == 0
```

Or, as a oneliner:

```
def ispangram(str1, alphabet = string.ascii_lowercase):
    return len(set(alphabet) - set(str1)) == 0
```